# Reaction Bar Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, widget

I'm looking for a good Reaction Bar plugin, generic and built for a web app.
I'm interested in all options.
I was very surprised that after an hour searching, I could only find WordPress and Mobile plugins that implement this. I'm trying to save development time, rather than write a full featured reactions bar with emojis. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated[image].

[image]

Comment: If you can't find one that works for you, that bar isn't anything complicated for you to learn and design.

Comment: Yes, its easy to implement, but what I'm looking for is a more full-featured plugin, with all the bells and whistles, pretty icons, reaction tally screen *see image2*. ect. Something with analytics baked into it, where I simple need to tie into my dB, would be amazing. I must be searching for the wrong thing, because I would think the search would easily yield many jquery/js web plugins. So far, I only find mobile related or wordpress. Crunch always, just trying to save myself time. Any suggestions are appreciated.